# "Please commit your changes" git error when trying to update packages

Tags: arch-linux, aur

When I run `yay -Syu` to update packages on my Arch Linux machine, I get this error:

```
 -> error fetching libcamera-git: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        PKGBUILD
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting 
         context: exit status 1
```

How do I fix this problem so I can update my packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try removing the package in question by `yay -Rs libcamera-git` and reinstall it.

Or you could go in the `libcamera-git` folder and do `git checkout .`, removing the not committed changes.